# Python: Function to return index starting from the end for a string

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

Is there a function to return the end index instead of the start index of a substring. For example, for

```
string = 'the rain in spain stays mainly in the plain'
```

`string.foo('mainly ')` returns 31, instead of having to use `string.index('mainly ')+len('mainly ')`?

Comment: probably a regular expression that looks for space after 'mainly'

Comment: You _may_ accomplish it using regexp or splitting etc. but using a `+len()` would be _much_ more easier. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do so, but it seems like `+len()` is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily implemented in two lines:

```
def get_sub_end(s, sub):
    f = s.find(sub)
    return f if f == -1 else f + len(sub)
```

Usage:

```
test_str = 'the rain in spain stays mainly in the plain'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_sub_end(test_str, "mainly ")  # >>> 31
    print get_sub_end(test_str, "undefined ")  # >>> -1
```